# size_t to unsigned int (from API function)

Tags: c++, size-t

I am using the Oracle API to access a database and this API has a function `readBuffer(char * buffer, unsigned int size);` to which I cannot make any changes.

I have a class that uses this API and the signature of my function currently takes a `std::string` and an `unsigned int` for the size, the problem is that when I pass `std::string.size()` to the size argument of my function, I get a warning from my compiler that converting from `size_t` to `unsigned int` could cause data loss.

I wondered if there is a **valid way** to convert the `size_t` to an `unsigned int` so I can pass it to my API and not get a warning from the compiler?

I understand the purpose of size_t and searching google for this conversion turns up a lot of results that say "change the function to take a size_t arg" but I **CANNOT** change the signature of my API in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: size_t is actually nothing else than an usigned int type. The problem is that the length of size_t is not exactly defined, if your system defines it to have more bits that a "normal" unsigned int, that you can do nothing to avoid a possible data loss. Does the warning also appear when casting explicitly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, write a helper function that will check whether such conversion is valid and throw an exception otherwise. Something like:

```
unsigned int convert( size_t what )
{
    if( what > UINT_MAX ) {
       throw SomeReasonableException();
    }
    return static_cast<unsigned int>( what );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like this idea. Practically it is unlikely that the size of a string gets beyond 32bits (4GB), but it is a nice practice.

Comment: `boost::numeric_cast` does this, more or less.

Answer (score 5):

Well, do a `static_cast<unsigned int>(mystring.size())`.

The reason is that `std::size_t` is usually pointer-size, but there are 64 bit platforms on which an `int` is still 32 bits. In this case, the only reason for data loss would be if the string in question had a length of more than 2^32 bytes.

If you know that this won't happen, put an `assert` somewhere to catch this case and `static_cast` the compiler to silence.

Answer (score 4):

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(str.size());
```

If you want to be paranoid:

```
if (static_cast<unsigned int>(str.size()) != str.size()) 
  throw ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the conversion using the

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(your_variable)
```

construct. Of course the correct way would be for the API to accept `size_t`...

Answer (score 1):

The risk here is that `size_t` might be larger than (`unsigned`) `int`, and thus you cannot safely convert if that is the case.

For instance, it's conceivable that `int` is 32 bits, while `size_t` is 64 bits. I don't know such a system/configuration off the top of my head, but it could occur.

For most "reasonable" systems, both will be at least 32 bits, and a single 4 GB string is still (perhaps) unlikely to occur.

So then you could just cast, that would be valid but it would not be "safe" for all possible systems and corner cases.

Comment: "I don't know such a system/configuration off the top of my head" - 64 bit Windows, 64 bit linux.